# building wix managed Custom Actions in .net 4.0

Tags: wix, wix-extension

We just recently upgraded all our code base to .net 4.0, and are trying to build custom actions in our installer using .net 4.0.

We are using wix 3.5 to do that, I am getting BadImageException, saying its built using a newer version of .net runtime than currently loaded.

does wix 3.5's makesxca utility support .net 4.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `<supportedRuntime>` version in the CustomAction.config to "v4.0"? I didn't try myself, it is just a guess. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) is referenced as the explanation.