# wix sfxca binding to CLR v 2.0 instead of v4.0

Tags: wix

Iam building managed custom actions using .net 4.0, but when i package the installer and run it,it fails giving me "assembly is built by newer version" error.

In the install log I can also see that the SfxCA is binding to v2.0 instead of 4.0, how can i configure it so it loads the v 4.0 version

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023790/building-wix-managed-custom-actions-in-net-4-0/3024076#3024076) is helpful.